# GD Library image creation problem

Tags: php, jquery, gd

I am having a problem with a gd library issue.  When I use the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {

    function repeat(str, num) {
        return new Array( num + 1 ).join( str );
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
            $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul'),
            $items = $slider.find('> li'),
            $single = $items.filter(':first'),

            singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(), 
            visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth), // note: doesn't include padding or border
            currentPage = 1,
            pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);            


        // 1. Pad so that 'visible' number will always be seen, otherwise create empty items
        if (($items.length % visible) != 0) {
            $slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length % visible)));
            $items = $slider.find('> li');
        }

        // 2. Top and tail the list with 'visible' number of items, top has the last section, and tail has the first
        $items.filter(':first').before($items.slice(- visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(0, visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items = $slider.find('> li'); // reselect

        // 3. Set the left position to the first 'real' item
        $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);

        // 4. paging function
        function gotoPage(page) {
            var dir = page < currentPage ? -1 : 1,
                n = Math.abs(currentPage - page),
                left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;

            $wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollLeft : '+=' + left
            }, 500, function () {
                if (page == 0) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible * pages);
                    page = pages;
                } else if (page > pages) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);
                    // reset back to start position
                    page = 1;
                } 

                currentPage = page;
            });                

            return false;
        }

        $wrapper.after('<a class="arrow back">&lt;</a><a class="arrow forward">&gt;</a>');

        // 5. Bind to the forward and back buttons
        $('a.back', this).click(function () {
            return gotoPage(currentPage - 1);                
        });

        $('a.forward', this).click(function () {
            return gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
        });

        // create a public interface to move to a specific page
        $(this).bind('goto', function (event, page) {
            gotoPage(page);
        });
    });  
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.infiniteCarousel').infiniteCarousel();

  $("a.pictureThumb").fancybox({
        'autoScale'     : true,
        'autoDimension' : true,
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   300, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : true, 
        'hideOnContentClick': false 
    });
});
</script>
```

With this as the image generator, the only thing that comes out is what looks like programming code instead of an image.  This script worked with a different scroller, but since I put this new scroller script (seen above), I am having problems with it generating an image (IE it just shows the loading icon), FireFox actually shows the programming code.

Here is the code that is making the call to the GD function:

```
<div class="infiniteCarousel">
  <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <?php 
      do { ?>
          <li><a class="pictureThumb" href="picture.php?imgID=<?php $pieces = explode('_', $row_rsPictures['PictureFile']); echo $pieces[0]."_".$pieces[1]."_".$pieces[2]; if ($pieces[3] == "NN"){ echo "_NN_".$pieces[4]."_".$pieces[5];; } else { echo "_".$pieces[3]."_".$pieces[4]; } ?>&thumb=Y" title="&lt;a href=&#x27;addToCart.php?T=Pic?ID=<?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureID']; ?>&#x27; target=&#x27;_parent&#x27; style=&#x27;color:#fe6d00&#x27;  &gt;Add This Image To Your Shopping Cart&lt;/a&gt;<br><?php echo $row_rsPictures['BoatName'];if($row_rsPictures['BoatNumber'] != "") {
                                     echo " #".$row_rsPictures['BoatNumber'];
                                     } ?><br>driven by: <?php echo $row_rsPictures['DriverName']; ?> at the <?php
                  $AssocName_array = explode('_', $row_rsPictures['Acronym']);
                  $AssocName = $AssocName_array[0];
                  if ($AssocName == "Various") {
                    $AssocName = "";
                    }            
                  if ($row_rsPictures['DateTo'] != ""){
                  $EventYear = date("Y", strtotime($row_rsPictures['DateTo']));
                  }
                    else { $EventYear = "";
                    }
                  echo $EventYear." ".$AssocName." ".$row_rsPictures['EventName'];?><br>Picture Viewed (<?php echo $row_rsPictures['Views']; ?>) since posted on <?php echo date("n-j-Y", strtotime($row_rsPictures['DatePosted'])); ?>" rel="group">
            <img src="../images/gallery/<?php $raceYear = explode('_', $row_rsPictures['EventOverlay']); echo $raceYear[0]; ?>/<?php echo $row_rsPictures['EventOverlay']; ?>/thumb/<?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureFile']; ?>.jpg" alt="FileName: <?php echo $row_rsPictures['PictureFile'];?>"></a></li>
          <?php  
          } while ($row_rsPictures = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPictures));
          mysql_data_seek($rsPictures, 0);
          ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and the separate php file that generates the image.

```
<?php  
$filename = explode("_", $_GET['imgID']);
$folder = $filename[0];
$subFolder = $filename[0]."_".$filename[1]."_".$filename[2];
if($filename[3] == "NN") {
    $subFolder = $subFolder."_NN";
    }
$shot = "../images/gallery/".$folder."/".$subFolder."/".$_GET['imgID'].".jpg";
$watermark = "../images/gallery/watermark.png";

header("Content-type: image/jpg");
$photoImage = ImageCreateFromJPEG($shot); 
ImageAlphaBlending($photoImage, true); 
$logoImage2 = ImageCreateFromPNG($watermark);

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 16);
$im2 = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 10);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
//imagefilledrectangle($photoImage, 0, 0, 796, 15, $white);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im2, 128, 128, 128);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im2, 255, 0, 0);
//$im = imagecreatetruecolor(796, 25);
$text = $_GET['imgID'];
$text2 = 'COPYRIGHT 1997 - 2011 - DRAGBOATS.COM - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED';
$text3 = '^ THIS BAR WILL NOT APPEAR ON PURCHASED PRINTS ^';
//$black = imagecolorallocate($photoImage, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 2, 10, 1, $text, $white);
imagestring($im, 2, 440, 1, $text2, $white);
imagestring($im2, 1, 290, 1, $text3, $white);

ImageCopy($photoImage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 16);
ImageCopy($photoImage, $im2, 0, 17, 0, 0, 800, 10);
ImageCopy($photoImage, $logoImage2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 525); 

ImageJPEG($photoImage); // output to browser 

ImageDestroy($photoImage); 
ImageDestroy($logoImage2);
?>
```

Somewhere there is a conflict that is causing the problem and I can't find it.

Any help is appreciated.

The actual page can be found at http://randykrohn.com/gallery/pictures_test.php?BoatID=881

Comment: Not sure whether it's the problem, but your JPG content type header should be `image/jpeg` notice the `e`

Comment: No, that didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're outputting the raw image data (the bytes in the .jpg) file into the gallery popup, with an innappropriate header so that the imgae is being interpreted as text and not an image.

If that last chunk of code under "... the call to GD function" is all in one file, that would explain why. You're outputting a chunk of html, followed by the raw image data, which then gets inserted into the gallery popup. The `Content-type` header cannot take effect as you've already output some html. If you check your error logs (and/or actually enable errors/warnings), you'd no doubt see the usual "cannot modify headers, output started at line XXX" warnings from PHP.

Comment: The moderator must have modified the post.  This php code is its own separate file. For some reason they lumped it together.

Comment: I'd done that edit, since you didn't have an explicit separator between those two files and the `<?php` portion had fallen outside the code formatting. I've split it up explicitly now.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.  I just made some edits to it for it to be more clear.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set php memory limit to 96M (128M - recommended) in `php.ini` file. If you have no access to that file simply add `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` to your php file. It must help to solve the issue.

Comment: Didn't help, but figured it out on my own.  Needed to tell FancyBox to open the link explicitly as an image (ie: fancybox({'type' : 'image'});

Alls well now!  Thanks for you help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't help, but figured it out on my own. Needed to tell FancyBox to open the link explicitly as an image (ie: fancybox({'type' : 'image'}); Alls well now! Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: You can accept the  answer for your own question.Do it to help some body else